# T-SQL update with switch-case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, switch-statement

I want implement this pseudocode in t-sql

```
UPDATE Resources SET [Path]= CASE ([Path].Substring([Path].LastIndexOf('.')))
                            WHEN '.jpg' THEN '/image.jpg'
                            WHEN '.png' THEN '/image.jpg'
                            WHEN '.avi' THEN '/video.jpg' 
                            WHEN '.mkv' THEN '/video.jpg'
```

for it I use this solution

```
UPDATE Resources SET [Path] = CASE (SUBSTRING([Path], LEN([Path]) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([Path])) + 1, 3))                
                                        WHEN '.jpg' THEN '/image.jpg'
                                        WHEN '.png' THEN '/image.jpg'
                                        WHEN '.avi' THEN '/video.jpg' 
                                        WHEN '.mkv' THEN '/video.jpg'
                                     END
```

but it is does not return expected result.

Can anyone give me working version please?

Comment: do you think that the solution is only in "3" changing to "4"? What about case usage, is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your read of the extension is wrong, instead try:

```
SUBSTRING(Path, LEN(Path) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Path)) + 1, LEN(Path))
```

(Using `LEN(Path)` as the read length; fine if it overflows the end of the string and allows for n-character extensions)

Answer (score 8):

```
UPDATE 
  Resources 
SET
  Path = CASE SUBSTRING(Path, LEN(Path) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Path)) + 1, 4)
           WHEN '.jpg' THEN '/image.jpg'
           WHEN '.png' THEN '/image.jpg'
           WHEN '.avi' THEN '/video.jpg' 
           WHEN '.mkv' THEN '/video.jpg'
         END
```

Comment: +1, you beat me to updating my answer to include changing the third arg to 4 :)

Comment: do you think that the solution is only in "3" changing to "4"?
What about case usage, is it right?

Comment: @Tomalak: instead of the complex substring, parsename will make the things simpler.

Comment: @dhinesh PARSENAME will blow up when there are more than 3 dots in the name. Wrong function for that problem, much too brittle. Even if there are less than 3 dots in the name, it is impossible to state *"take the last part"* with that function.

Comment: @Artur Keyan: Yes, that was the main problem. Please do not change your question after it has been answered (I've rolled back your last edit). The usage of CASE is all right.

Comment: @Tomalak: I agree that if there are more than 3 dots then there is a problem. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `SUBSTRING([Path], LEN([Path]) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([Path])) + 1, 3)`,
try using `lower(right([Path], 4))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [ParseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

```
UPDATE Resources SET [Path] = CASE (Parsename(Path,1))                
                                        WHEN 'jpg' THEN '/image.jpg'
                                        WHEN 'png' THEN '/image.jpg'
                                        WHEN 'avi' THEN '/video.jpg' 
                                        WHEN 'mkv' THEN '/video.jpg'
                                     END
```

Comment: PARSENAME is intended for parsing SQL object names (eg. AdventureWorks.dbo.Customers), `Path` is not an *object name* so PARSENAME is not suited for the job

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Resources SET ThumbnailPath = CASE SUBSTRING(ThumbnailPath, LEN(ThumbnailPath) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(ThumbnailPath)) + 1, LEN(ThumbnailPath))             
                    WHEN '.doc'   THEN @root + '/doc.png'
                    WHEN '.docx'  THEN @root + '/doc.png'
                    WHEN '.jpg'   THEN @root + '/image.png'
                    WHEN '.jpeg'  THEN @root + '/image.png'
                    WHEN '.gif'   THEN @root + '/image.png'
                    WHEN '.png'   THEN @root + '/image.png'
                    WHEN '.ppt'   THEN @root + '/ppt.png'
                    WHEN '.pptx'  THEN @root + '/ppt.png'
                    WHEN '.pdf'   THEN @root + '/pdf.png'
                    ELSE               @root + '/other.png'
                 END
```

thank you I finaly use this

Answer (score 0):

This script will assure that you do not update all rows every time you run the script. It will only update changes.

```
UPDATE r
SET ThumbnailPath = newvalue
FROM Resources r
cross apply 
(SELECT right(ThumbnailPath, patindex('%_.%', reverse(ThumbnailPath))) T) a                 
cross apply 
(SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN a.T in ('doc','docx' )            THEN @root + '/doc.png' 
                    WHEN a.T in ('jpg','jpeg','gif','png') THEN @root + '/image.png' 
                    WHEN a.T in ('ppt','pptx')             THEN @root + '/ppt.png' 
                    WHEN a.T = 'pdf'                       THEN '/pdf.png'
                    ELSE @root + '/other.png' 
                 END newvalue)  b
WHERE r.ThumbnailPath <> b.newvalue
```